# I can't update script on Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I use Google App in my company, and I often have a prob when I update my script.

When I Update my script , my Webpage on Google sites is not updated , and for long time.
I must create a new script when I update my script.

Can I resolve this problem ?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to *publish* your code:

**A) Either by deploying a new version, which is done as follows:**

1. File -> Manage Versions
2. Add a new version -> Close dialog
3. Publish -> Deploy as web app
4. Select the version added -> Update

**B) Or by always using your latest code**

1. Publish -> Deploy as web app
2. Under the web app URL, click on the latest code button.
3. This way, any change done and saved will automatically be updated upon a refresh

Comment: What is the end of your script url? `dev` or `exec`?

Comment: my end of the script is  "exec"

Comment: then add a new version and update, as mentioned in my original answer, A) part.

Comment: it sounds crazy if we have to create a new version every time we add a simple bracket!

Comment: We don't. We can use the latest code, as I've mentioned above :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in the documentation. You need to first save a new version in the versions dialog. Then you need to re-publish it using the new version number.

Comment: I make a new version everytime but , i can update and deploy , it's not working.    
it's a problem with my application ?  because I use GUI Google App Script.