# Google apps script won't update app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am brand new to this and I know this is probably something simple but I just can't seem to get this working. I found this app script online that lets people upload files to my Google Drive but when I try to change anything in it and save it doesn't reflect in the app. I try to add CSS or update the text in Google Script editor then press Save then Run doGet function but nothing pops up to show me the page and the app doesn't change at all. It is deployed and authorized already.

server.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Student Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

form.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<?!= include('style'); ?>

<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
<input type="file" name="myFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't update script on Google App Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453265/i-cant-update-script-on-google-app-script)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to  @billy98111

Each time you deploy your web app it uses the same version. That's why it does not update.

Once you made changes, create new version then deploy it. Then when you deploy choose the the version you want to run

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the URL with 'exec' on the end, that URL only serves the last version deployed, it won't show you the development version.  Secondly, in order for any client side HTML, JavaScript, CSS to be displayed, you must refresh the browser tab.  You don't need to refresh the browser tab to see results of any changes in `.gs` server side code.  I have experienced situations where it seems like I needed to reload the browser, or reboot my computer to get something to work, but I can't verify that, and it could have just been a stupid mistake on my part.  If it turns out to be none of those issues, let me know.  I highly doubt it has anything to do with your code itself.  If it's a shared file, and you are not the owner, there can be situations where the owner didn't authorize a new permission, so new code that needs a different permission that had not been authorized before won't run.

Comment: Thanks for your help I think I have it figured out now. When trying to deploy it again I finally noticed the little link that says "Test web app for your latest code". When I clicked that it was able to reflect the changes I have made and any current changes I am making (link ends in /dev). To deploy the app again to make a new version and release it I went to File > Manage Revisions. After that I just deployed it as normal by pressing the cloud icon and selecting the 2nd version I made. I thought this was like writing scripts in a webpage but it's not. Take some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't published your app yet!

You need to go to Publish, Deploy as Web App.

There you'll have to generate a new version and them you can Deploy it, after that, you'll get a window showing the Deployed URL (the official URL) and a test URL (in order to test each save you make on your code):

[image]

After that if you need to publish new modifications officially, you have to go to File, manage Versions and create a new Version, after that you choose this new version on the Deploy menu again.