# Modifying script for Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, var

To log sensor data to Google sheets using ESP32, I found a script online to accomplish that. However, I want to modify it so that I could have additional data fields logged. I don't know much about JavaScript but tried to add a new var and modify the code but it doesn't work. Here is the original script:

```
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log("--- doGet ---");
 
 var tag = "",
     value = "";
 
  try {
 
    // this helps during debuggin
    if (e == null){e={}; e.parameters = {tag:"test",value:"-1"};}
 
    tag = e.parameters.tag;
    value = e.parameters.value;
 
    // save the data to spreadsheet
    save_data(tag, value);
 
 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Wrote:\n  tag: " + tag + "\n  value: " + value);
 
  } catch(error) { 
    Logger.log(error);    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("oops...." + error.message 
                                            + "\n" + new Date() 
                                            + "\ntag: " + tag +
                                            + "\nvalue: " + value);
  }  
}
 
// Method to save given data to a sheet
function save_data(tag, value){
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---"); 
 
 
  try {
    var dateTime = new Date();
 
    // Paste the URL of the Google Sheets starting from https thru /edit
    // For e.g.: https://docs.google.com/..../edit 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3NY0nbnJgx_RHJeG6GckfVesUXBI5rgxmTJ40yX0vE/edit");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Datalogger");
 
 
    // Get last edited row from DataLogger sheet
    var row = dataLoggerSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
 
 
    // Start Populating the data
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + row).setValue(row -1); // ID
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B" + row).setValue(dateTime); // dateTime
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(tag); // tag
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(value); // value
 
 
    // Update summary sheet
    summarySheet.getRange("B1").setValue(dateTime); // Last modified date
    // summarySheet.getRange("B2").setValue(row - 1); // Count 
  }
 
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
 
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---"); 
}
```

Here is the version with my additions:

```
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log("--- doGet ---");
 
 var tag = "",
     value = "",
     tag2 = "",
     val2 = "";

  try {
 
    // this helps during debuggin
    if (e == null){e={}; e.parameters = {tag:"test",value:"-1", tag2: "test2", val2: "-1"};}
 
    tag = e.parameters.tag;
    value = e.parameters.value;
    tag2 = e.parameters.tag2;
    val2 = e.parameters.val2;
 
    // save the data to spreadsheet
    save_data(tag, value, tag2, val2);
 
 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Wrote:\n  tag: " + tag + "\n  value: " + value + "\n  tag2: " + tag2 + "\n  val2: " + val2);
 
  } catch(error) { 
    Logger.log(error);    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("oops...." + error.message 
                                            + "\n" + new Date() 
                                            + "\ntag: " + tag
                                            + "\nvalue: " + value
                                            + "\n  tag2: " + tag2
                                            + "\n  val2: " + val2);
  }   
}
 
// Method to save given data to a sheet
function save_data(tag, value, tag2, val2){
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---"); 
 
 
  try {
    var dateTime = new Date();
 
    // Paste the URL of the Google Sheets starting from https thru /edit
    // For e.g.: https://docs.google.com/..../edit 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3NY0nbnJgx_RHJeG6GckfVesUXBI5rgxmTJ40yX0vE/edit");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sht31_1");
 
 
    // Get last edited row from DataLogger sheet
    var row = dataLoggerSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
 
 
    // Start Populating the data
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + row).setValue(row -1); // ID
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B" + row).setValue(dateTime); // dateTime
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(tag); // tag
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(val); // value
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("E" + row).setValue(tag2); // tag
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("F" + row).setValue(val2); // value
 
 
    // Update summary sheet
    summarySheet.getRange("B1").setValue(dateTime); // Last modified date
    // summarySheet.getRange("B2").setValue(row - 1); // Count 
  }
 
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
 
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---"); 
}
```

So when I send the data using a GET request, only values of original variables (tag and value) are posted to the google sheet. Could you please tell how can I fix it?

EDIT: I have tried making a GET request manually using Postman to test if the script works. Here is the request:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwibc1auwDUtlRPIkIpO53FM6DivTLLNscMjBPGOaeajcVkZb6i7LH6gwp2Lw8I174B/exec?tag=Temp&value=21.13&tag2=Humid&val2=47.87

Comment: Could you share an example sheet to check the expected behavior with the script and the actual behavior? a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue would be helpful so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google apps script won't update app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034291/google-apps-script-wont-update-app)

Comment: @GabrielCarballo here is the link to the google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3NY0nbnJgx_RHJeG6GckfVesUXBI5rgxmTJ40yX0vE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Kos no I don't think it's a version issue. I have making a GET request in Postman but it still doesn't record the second variable. I think it's the javascript. My modifications to add the extra variable seems to me the most likely culprit

Comment: @GabrielCarballo, I have shared also the GET request that may be useful to test the script

Comment: I think that in your script, `val` of `dataLoggerSheet.getRange("D" + row).setValue(val);` is not declared. In this case, it's `value`? I thought that this might be your current issue. And also, `summarySheet` is not declared. I think that it will be the next error. Please be careful about this. And, when you modified the script, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: Yeah very mysterious issue, probably it's a bug in apps script then, I don't see any other reason, it should be a bug