# google scripts- Script function not found: doGet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, triggers

I'm new to JS.

**Problem Statement:**

Test code is working well but when I publish this code its shows an error (Script function not found: doGet).

I have tried to make modifications and read the google documentation but am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function sendToSpreadsheet(data,strValue) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Res');

  var list = "";

  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  return list;
}
```

Comment: we have way too little information to establish what the reason is. You're probably trying to make a point that `doGet` exists by showing it to us **but** it's also very important to know where it is and whether or not there is a syntax error or what not.

Comment: I have two files  , Code.gs and Index.html. While testing Everything works file but error shows up on publishing.

Comment: It could be that you didn't publish the latest version. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453265/i-cant-update-script-on-google-app-script/21458305#21458305) to make sure you're publishing the latest version